# SQL Server Union Eliminate Last Rows With Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get results with two union clause. I eliminate duplicate rows with distinct. But i have to keep first row but distinct eliminate first rows. How can i keep first rows?

```
//for example in this sql first i have expected PRodId=10 first but it is last. 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=10
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=120
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=400
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=10) prods
```

Comment: Why do you have `prodId = 10` twice?

Comment: What is the point of this query? to find which product codes (10,120,240 - probably parameters) exist in the product table?

Answer (score 2):

Why the Union All?

```
Select Distinct ProdId 
 From Products 
 Where ProdId in (10,120,400)
 Order By ProdID
```

Comment: Feel free to remove the `Distinct`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Added it afterwards just in case ProdID was not distinct

Comment: `ProdID` in `Products`? In that case I'll ring the design alarm

Answer (score 0):

Order by product id, if that is why you expect 10 first..  you can't guarantee the order of sql query results unless you provide an `order by` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=10
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=120
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=400
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ProdId FROM Products WHERE ProdId=10) prods
  ORDER BY prods.ProdId
```

Comment: in fact i need insertion order. i have to keep insertion order.

Comment: @Yargicx- then you need to store that in a column and order by that column.  If ProdId is autoincremented, then this should work.

Comment: I would recommend @john Cappelletti's answer, as well.  get rid of the `union all`s if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows in a particular order, then you *need* to include `order by` in the query.  In your case, you can add:

```
order by (case prodid when 10 then 1 when 120 then 2 when 400 then 3 end)
```

You can write the entire query as:

```
select distinct p.prodid
from products p
where prodid in (10, 120, 400)
order by (case prodid when 10 then 1 when 120 then 2 when 400 then 3 end);
```

Two notes:

- If there are no duplicates, then do not use `select distinct`.
- If you want the data in product id order, then just use `order by prodid`.

Comment: Feel free to remove the `Distinct`

Answer (score 0):

Without explicit ORDER BY, the order of rows in the result set returned to an application has nothing to do with ordering of the data source (table expression). Query optimizer is free to return rows in any order it "thinks" is faster.
Provide explicit ORDER BY in the query.